# DynamoDB - Remove key-value pair from Map

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

```json
{
  "ExHashKey": "id_asdfqe123",
  "Data": {
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to delete elements from the "Data" map by key. Is there a way to do this other than just retrieving the entire item, making changes, and then writing it to the DB again?

I've poked around the `UpdateExpressions` API a fair amount and I haven't found anything that's worked.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the below `UpdateExpression` to remove the key from Map data type.

```
var params = {
    TableName: "yourTableName",
    Key: {
        "ExHashKey": "id_asdfqe123"
    },
    UpdateExpression: "REMOVE Data.key1",
    ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW"
};
```